# В DataGrid не выводятся данные

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Подскажите,в чем может быть проблема?
Задание следующее-нужно вывести из куба все данные,и по нажатию на чекбокс определенного измерения,оно должно отображаться в DataGrid
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient;
using System.Data;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetDimensions();
            listBox.UpdateLayout();

        }

        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

        private void GetDimensions()
        {
            // prepare adomd connection
            using (AdomdConnection mdConn = new AdomdConnection())
            {
                mdConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Сергей;Initial Catalog=MultidimensionalProject1";
                mdConn.Open();

                // перебор кубов
                foreach (CubeDef cube in mdConn.Cubes)
                {
                    if (cube.Type != CubeType.Cube) continue;

                    // перебор измерений
                    foreach (Dimension dimension in cube.Dimensions)
                    {
                        // перебор иерархий
                        foreach (Hierarchy hierarchy in dimension.Hierarchies)
                        {

                            if (!hierarchy.Name.Contains("Id") && !hierarchy.Name.Contains("Measures")) listBox.Items.Add(hierarchy.UniqueName + ".[" + hierarchy.Name + "]");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }



        }

        private void BuildQuery()
        {


        }






        private void UpdateChart(string mdxQuery)
        {
            // prepare adomd connection
            using (AdomdConnection mdConn = new AdomdConnection())
            {
                mdConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Сергей;Initial Catalog=MultidimensionalProject1";
                mdConn.Open();
                AdomdCommand mdCommand = mdConn.CreateCommand();
                mdCommand.CommandText = mdxQuery;  // << MDX Query 

                // выполняем запрос, получаем CellSet
                CellSet cs;
                cs = mdCommand.ExecuteCellSet();

                // our method supports only 2-Axes CellSets
                if (cs.Axes.Count != 2) return;

                TupleCollection tuplesOnColumns = cs.Axes[0].Set.Tuples;
                TupleCollection tuplesOnRows = cs.Axes[1].Set.Tuples;

                // 2 дублирующиеся структуры данных для графиков и таблицы с данными
                var Data = new DataTable();


                if (tuplesOnColumns.Count > 0 && tuplesOnRows.Count > 0)
                {
                    // Создаем заголовки в таблице на основе названий
                    for (int m = 0; m < tuplesOnRows[0].Members.Count; m++)
                    {
                        Data.Columns.Add(tuplesOnRows[0].Members[m].ParentLevel.Name);
                    }
                    Data.Columns.Add(tuplesOnColumns[0].Members[0].Caption);

                    // Выводим строки с данными
                    for (int row = 0; row < tuplesOnRows.Count; row++)
                    {
                        int m = 0;
                        // объект - для занесения в таблицу данных
                        var o = new object[tuplesOnRows[row].Members.Count + tuplesOnColumns.Count];

                        for (; m < tuplesOnRows[row].Members.Count; m++)
                        {
                            // заносим названия измерений для таблицы (по колонкам)
                            o[m] = tuplesOnRows[row].Members[m].Caption;

                        }
                        // заносим непосредственно значения метрики (кол-во обращений) в последнюю колонку строки (для таблицы)
                        for (int col = 0; col < tuplesOnColumns.Count; col++)
                        {
                            o[m + col] = (cs.Cells[col, row].Value.ToString());
                        }
                        //добавляем строку таблицы
                        Data.Rows.Add(o);

                    }
                }
                // обновляем визуализацию данных
                try
                {
                    dataGrid.ItemsSource = Data.DefaultView;
                    dataGrid.Items.Refresh();

                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }



        }



        private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            var cb = sender as CheckBox;
            var item = cb.DataContext;
            listBox.SelectedItem = item;
            // выход, если задан пустой запрос
            if (listBox.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;

            // проверяем, установлен ли фильтр по кол-ву обращений
            bool filter = cbFilter.IsChecked == true && txtFilterValue.Text != "" && Convert.ToInt32(txtFilterValue.Text) >= 0;

            // первая часть запроса: количсество обращений
            string query = "SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Hits Count] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY {";
            // если установлен фильтр - добавляем его
            query += filter ? "filter (  {" : "";

            // перебираем все отмеченные измерения и добавляем их к запросу
            foreach (var i in listBox.SelectedItems)
            {
                query += " " + i.ToString() + ".ALLMEMBERS *";
            }

            // удаляем последний пробел со звездочкой
            query = query.Remove(query.Length - 2);

            // при наличии фильтра дописываем условие вида "[Measures].[Hits Count] > 500"
            query += filter ? "} , [Measures].[Hits Count] " + cbFilterMode.SelectedValue.ToString() + " " + Convert.ToInt32(txtFilterValue.Text) + ")" : "";

            //финальная часть запроса
            query += " } ON ROWS FROM [Почта]";
            UpdateChart(query);


        }
    }
}
```

исключение возникает

```
 // выполняем запрос, получаем CellSet
                CellSet cs;
                cs = mdCommand.ExecuteCellSet();
```

---

```
Необработанное исключение типа "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdErrorResponseException" в Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll
```

---

```
 <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="385" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="230" FontFamily="Segoe UI Black" Grid.Column="10">

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox  Content="{Binding Text}" 
      IsChecked="{Binding Checked ,Mode=TwoWay}" Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Вы под дебагом смотрели на каком моменте останавливается программа? Возможно где-то вылетает Exseption, попробуйте в функциях весь код обрамить в try{}catch(Exseption ex){MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }

Comment: @AlexsandrTer не чего не происходит,выполняется только GetDimensions()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить `DataGrid.Items.Refresh()`:

```
// обновляем визуализацию данных
    try
    {
      dataGrid.ItemsSource = Data.DefaultView;
      dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

В целом, при использовании WPF нужно применять привязки (Bindings) и паттерн MVVM. Код сразу становится "по полочкам".

Comment: не помогло,также не заносятся данные

Comment: @Сергей74rus: а как и где у вас вызывается метод BuildQuery()? Я вижу, что он объявлен как `private`.

Comment: я сейчас сделал что бы по кнопке его вызывать,через breakpoin посмотрел а у меня из listBox не читает значение выделенных checkbox , таким способом пытался listBox.SelectedItems.Count ,не подскажите другой вариант?

Comment: @Сергей74rus: не пойму как у вас реализован listBox. Покажите его xaml-разметку.  Попробуйте пойти от простого к сложному: для начала в BuildQuery() сделайте query фиксированной строкой, которая гарантированно получает данные из базы и передает их в dataGrid.

Comment: я изменил вопрос,из listBox достал checkbox, но теперь другая беда

Comment: Тема закрыта,все исправил.